# Dynamic table creation SQLSever

Tags: sql-server

I have several tables in SQL sever worth of Employee data including ID's and clock in times. I need to create a report to show clocking times for each day for each employee. i have done this with the below code. However as the clock ins are only recorded if there is an entry i need to show working days where there are no records for a clock in for employees. I've thought about making a table of working days in 2019/2020 including data each employee on each day and using this to join however the table would need continual updating when somebody new starts.

Is there any way the table can update itself with employee numbers and copy working days?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

```sql
select distinct cast(a.DET_NUMBER as varchar) as 'Frontier ID',
    e.CDN_CARD_ID,
    CONCAT (a.DET_G1_NAME1, ' ', a.DET_SURNAME) as 'Name',
    c.POS_TITLE as 'Position',
    c.POS_L3_CD as 'Department',
    c.POS_L4_CD as 'Department 2',
    cast(a.DET_DATE_JND as date) as 'Start Date',
    cast(b.TER_DATE as date) as 'Leaving Date',
    CONCAT (d.DET_G1_NAME1, ' ', d.DET_SURNAME) as 'Team Manager',
    f.CLO_DATE2,
    min(CLO_TIME2) over (partition by f.CLO_DATE2, e.CDN_CARD_ID) as earliest_time,
    max(CLO_TIME2) over (partition by f.CLO_DATE2, e.CDN_CARD_ID) as latiest_time
from EMDET a
left outer join EMTER b on a.DET_NUMBER = b.DET_NUMBER
left outer join EMPOS c on a.DET_NUMBER = c.DET_NUMBER
left outer join EMDET d on c.POS_MANEMPNO = d.DET_NUMBER
left outer join TACDN e on a.DET_NUMBER = e.DET_NUMBER
left outer join TACLO f on e.CDN_CARD_ID = f.CLO_CARD_NO
Where (b.TER_DATE is null or c.POS_END>=GETDATE())
  and c.POS_TITLE is not null
  and (c.POS_END<=Cast('1992-01-01' as datetime) or c.POS_END>=GETDATE())
  and f.CLO_DATE >='2019-01-01'
order by [Team Manager] asc,
         e.CDN_CARD_ID asc,
         f.CLO_DATE2 asc
```

Comment: Why would you need that table for each employee? you just need a calendar table that can be simulated with a CTE and a table for Non-working days is easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a calendar with a CTE

```
DECLARE @Start DATE = '2018-1-1', @End DATE = GETDATE()
;WITH 
dates AS
(
    SELECT thedate = @Start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,dates.thedate)
    FROM dates
    WHERE dateadd(day,1,dates.thedate) <= @End
)
SELECT * 
FROM dates c
OPTION (maxrecursion 0);
```

Then filter to exclude non-working days (weekens: direct in yourquery, holidays, vacations, permits, etc from other table)

Left join with your actual query