# Join CTE Tables SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below CTE table that I am joining to various employee data using  clockin dates and times for each employee in the table. I need to join this table TACLO onto the CTE so that the query returns the data matched to the dates on the CTE table, however when I try inner, outer, left or right joins only the records which have a clockin on the matched days appear, but I need to see both.

How can I get this?

```
DECLARE @Start DATE = '2018-1-1', @End DATE = GETDATE()
;WITH 
dates AS
(   SELECT thedate = @Start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(day,1,dates.thedate)
    FROM dates
    WHERE dateadd(day,1,dates.thedate) <= @End)

select distinct cast(a.DET_NUMBER as varchar) as 'Frontier ID',
e.CDN_CARD_ID, 
CONCAT (a.DET_G1_NAME1,' ',a.DET_SURNAME) as 'Name',
c.POS_TITLE as 'Position',
c.POS_L3_CD as 'Department', 
c.POS_L4_CD as 'Department 2', 
cast(a.DET_DATE_JND as date) as 'Start Date', 
cast(b.TER_DATE as date) as 'Leaving Date', 
CONCAT (d.DET_G1_NAME1,' ',d.DET_SURNAME) as 'Team Manager', 
f.CLO_DATE2,
min(f.CLO_TIME2) over (partition by f.CLO_DATE2,e.CDN_CARD_ID) as earliest_time,
max(f.CLO_TIME2) over (partition by f.CLO_DATE2,e.CDN_CARD_ID) as latiest_time, q.thedate

from EMDET a
left outer join EMTER b on a.DET_NUMBER = b.DET_NUMBER
left outer join EMPOS c on a.DET_NUMBER = c.DET_NUMBER
left outer join EMDET d on c.POS_MANEMPNO = d.DET_NUMBER
left outer join TACDN e on a.DET_NUMBER = e.DET_NUMBER
left outer join TACLO f on e.CDN_CARD_ID = f.CLO_CARD_NO
left outer join dates q on f.CLO_DATE2 = q.thedate

Where (b.TER_DATE is null or c.POS_END>=GETDATE()) and 
c.POS_TITLE is not null and 
(c.POS_END<=Cast('1992-01-01' as datetime) or c.POS_END>=GETDATE()) and q.thedate = '2019-02-13'

order by [Team Manager] asc, e.CDN_CARD_ID asc, f.CLO_DATE2 asc

OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: You are putting  and q.thedate = '2019-02-13' on your where clause, this will return only the matching records.

Comment: Hi PSK i want to see null records on this day i.e. when employees havent clocked in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic table creation SQLSever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667343/dynamic-table-creation-sqlsever)

Comment: Your query is almost the opposite of how you describe it.  So you say you have a  "CTE table that i am joining to various employee data " (sic), but what you actually have is a load of employee data that you join to a date table with a `LEFT JOIN`, which is then "converted" into an `INNER JOIN` as you have criteria in your `WHERE` clause, as noted above by PSK.

Comment: Hi SMor, this was also my post keep getting slightly closer to the correct outcome

Comment: Try moving `and q.thedate = '2019-02-13'` from the `WHERE` clause into the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to your `dates` CTE.  That might make your query work as you expect, but there's really so much else wrong here that I wouldn't know where to start...